# if nav link matches page_id change color

Tags: jquery, variables, nav, pathname

ok so heres my nav setup

```
<div id="headerMenu">
            <ul>  
                <li style="width:147px"><a href="/?page_id=92" class="menuHov"><span>ABOUT<br/>ABOUT</span></a></li>
                <li style="width:186px"><a href="/?page_id=64" class="menuHov"><span>STOCKISTS<br/>STOCKISTS</span></a></li>
                <li style="width:146px"><a href="/?page_id=96" class="menuHov"><span>PRESS<br/>PRESS</span></a></li>
                <li style="width:128px"><a href="/?category_name=blogs" class="menuHov"><span>BLOG<br/>BLOG</span></a></li>
                <li style="width:70px"><a href="/?page_id=89 " class="menuHov"><span>CONTACT<br/>CONTACT</span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

i need a jquery script to recognize the page_id variable and the href and if they're the same, change color... let me know if you need anymore info...

heres what i tried so far.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.menuHov[href$=' + window.location.pathname + ']').css('color', '#fae349');
});
```

but that changes everything  because i guess it doesn't recognize the href as a pathname

Comment: so maybe like a... if page_id in url matches page_id in href, change color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var page_id = getParameterByName("page_id");
    $("a.menuHov[href$=" + page_id + "]").css('color', '#fae349');
})
```

Include the query string parser from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-in-javascript)

```
function getParameterByName( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the forward slash/? in the URL.
Try this it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
   $('a.menuHov[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').css('color', '#fae349'); 
});
```

Working example @ jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/CeZCY/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var link = window.location;
     var t_arr = new Array();
     t_arr = link.split('/');
     $("a.menuHov[href$='"+t_arr[1]+"']").css('color', '#fae349');     
});
```

Is it okay?